# How to reset OS X 10.8 to boot?

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I ran the `dd` command on `/dev/rdisk1` and now OS X is not starting.

Is it possible to recover the OS? I have access to recovery mode, but Disk Utility says that the disk is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can Erase the disk using Disk Utility (open Disk Utility, select the disk, then the Erase tab, and click Erase), then use the Reinstall OS X option in the Recovery HD utilities list, following the instructions as a normal OS X install.

Alternatively, use Internet Recovery by booting with ⌘⌥R.

Comment: But in this case all my files would be lost?

Comment: @user67308 Yes. If you have backups, you could recover from that. Can you access the files in Terminal whilst booted into the Recovery HD?

Comment: The problem is that filevaul is on and i dont remember the password... But i have restore key, is it possible to get password by this key?